# Change ActionBar style: Bring text underneath icon

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

I have a tabbed application, which uses the theme Holo.Light

Is it possible to display the name of the tab UNDERNEATH the tab icons for higher API, for an Action Bar? If so, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom layout view and add that like this

```
ActionBar.Tab tabA= bar.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_tab);
```

"actionbar_custom_tab" is the my customized layout, here you can set icon and textview based on your requirement